# Dynamic set of publishers all emiting through the same flux

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor

I am trying to build a kind of hub service that can emit through a hot Flux (output) but you can also register/unregister Flux producers/publishers (input)

I know I can do something like:

```
    class Hub<T> {
        /**
         * @return unregister function
         */
        Function<Void, Void> registerProducer(final Flux<T> flux) { ... }

        Disposable subscribe(Consumer<? super T> consumer) {
            if (out == null) { 
                // obviously this will not work!
                out = Flux.merge(producer1, producer2, ...).share();
            }
            return out;
        }
    }
```

... but as these "producers" are registered and unregistered, how do I add a new flux source to the existing subscribed to flux? or remove a unregistered source from it?

TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Flux` is immutable by design, so as you've implied in the question, there's no way to just "update" an existing `Flux` in situ.

Usually I'd recommend avoiding using a `Processor` directly. However, this is one of the (rare-ish) cases where a `Processor` is probably the only sane option, since you essentially want to be publishing elements dynamically based on the producers that you're registering. Something similar to:

```
class Hub<T> {

    private final FluxProcessor<T, T> processor;
    private final FluxSink<T> sink;

    public Hub() {
        this.processor = DirectProcessor.<T>create().serialize();
        this.sink = processor.sink();
    }

    public Disposable registerProducer(Flux<T> flux) {
        return flux.subscribe(sink::next);
    }

    public Flux<T> read() {
        return processor;
    }
}
```

If you want to remove a producer, then you can keep track of the `Disposable` returned from `registerProducer()` and call `dispose()` on it when done.

Comment: Hey again Michael, are you the only Flux expert on stackoverflow? :D
Thanks again! I didn't know about the FluxProcessor under the hood, this is indeed exactly what I am looking for. And Yep!, I could see this as being a real red flag in many situations. Cheers

Comment: Far from it! Simon is the real expert around here, I just give my best stab at things and hope that he comes and corrects me if I'm talking nonsense ;-)